# JQuery replace two static elements with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two static elements in my table `<tr class="item-row">` that I need to replace with data from an ajax call. I have them in place for other features of the form and currently are appending to them with the ajax data. I now have another need to 'replace' them with the same call instead of append?

My javascript line that appends is: `$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row">...` I'm not sure hoe to replace the item-row and keep it in the same location on the page as well as append th rest of the loop in ajax.

What I have works, it appends to the existing two, would it be better to just hide/delete the top two `item-row` after appending?

HTML:

```
      <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="recall-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">R</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$150.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="recall-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">R</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$95.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$95.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="hiderow">
        <td colspan="5">

        <img src="images/rows.png" width="30px" height="auto" id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row"/>                  
        <img src="images/products.png" width="30px" height="auto" href="javascript:;" id="fill-invoice" class="add-invoice" title="Add Invoice"/>
        <img src="images/products.png" width="30px" height="auto" href="javascript:;" id="recall_product" class="recall-product" title="Recall Product"/>

        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>
          <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
          <td class="total-value balance"><div id="owed" class="due">$0.00</div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

FORM.JS:

```
$('.recall-product').live('click',function(){

    var clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var auto_id = $('#auto_num').val();

    $("#product_div").css("display", "block");
    //alert(auto_id);
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'recall_product_fill.php?id='+auto_id,                         
        data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            populateSelectBoxes($('#product_div #ddproduct'), data);

            function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
                var products = [];
                $.each(data, function() {
                    products.push($(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">'+ this.product +'</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a><a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a></div></td><td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">'+ this.description +'</textarea></td><td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">'+ this.cost +'</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">'+ this.quantity +'</textarea></td><td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">'+ this.price +'</span></td></tr>'));
                    if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
                    bind();
                });
                $select.append(products.join(''));
            }

            function populateTableRow(data, selectedProductAutonum) {
                var products;
                $.each(data, function() {
                    if (this.autonum == selectedProductAutonum) {
                        products = this;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#product_div #ddproduct li').click(function(e) {
                var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
                populateTableRow(data, selection);
                $('ul').empty();

            });
        }
    });
update_total()
});
```

Comment: have you tried using `replaceWith()`?

Comment: I have not, my data may only have 1 result or many, so would I replace both with one? and how would that work?

Comment: To be honest it's not entirely clear what expected results are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements, if you need to replace your static tr's after ajax call, then you need to delete them first, and then append your newly created tr's from ajax after table header. I create a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/bt37gvxo/1/) for you.

Also I have several suggestions for your code style and used approach. First, you should never create any functions right into the response handlers. You should create function before ajax call and then only call it, instead of creating on each call. Second, try to separate your   `products.push` method into several small pieces to make your code more readable, you can define variables outside of ajax call and only reassign their values on each ajax call.

Comment: I think that might work, only issue is I have tried it as: `table>tr:nth-child(1)` and doesn't seem to be correct in my code? I do have another table above that one in my code - should I use `#item >tr`

Comment: any help on finding the 2nd table or by #id like `table#items>tr:nth-child(1)`

Comment: got it `$("table.items tr:nth-child(1)").after`